# Unable to call php file from Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, clipboard

I'm trying to call php file from my javascript but it doesn't works. No error but the it didn't works as per expected. Below is my code.

Javascript

```
function getImage() {
    obj = document.getElementById('paste-image');
    postTo = "http://clipboard.netau.net/Web/shoot.php";

    image = obj.getClipboardImageURL(postTo);

    if (image) {
        url = "shots/" + image;

        document.getElementById("target").src = url;
        document.getElementById("url").value = document.getElementById("target").src; // to get full path, hack, I know ;)
        document.getElementById("container").style.display = "";
    }
}
```

shoot.php

```
<?php   
$filename = uniqid() . '.jpg';
$result = file_put_contents( "./shots/" . $filename, file_get_contents('php://input') );
if (!$result) {
    print "error";
    exit();
}   
echo $filename;
?>
```

I've uploaded the code in free hosting . **clipboard.netau.net**

Comment: Is `#target` an `img` tag? If so, why are you assigning shoot.php to it?

Comment: There's no such method as getClipboardImageURL. Where did you get this from? It looks like you just copied it from http://pastebin.com/gJmeFGvK

Comment: i get the code from http://lassebunk.dk/2009/07/19/using-the-clipboard-to-post-images/

Comment: @Barmar the method is from my applet

Comment: Do you have Java (not Javascript) enabled in your browser? These days it's often disabled by default because of security concerns, and few sites depend on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use AJAX call -

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://xyz.abc.com/abc.php",true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var file = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
};
xmlhttp.send();
```

By this,you can get your complete php file in variable 'file'.